# An array cannot be converted implicitly to an iterable

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, iterable

As per the java documentation says :

The `Iterable<T>` allows an object to be used as the target of a for-each statement.

In java we can do the following :

```
for (final <? super T> : T[]) {...}
```

In this case, why java cannot consider an object of type T[] as being an Iterable, Because the following crashes with an incomptaible types compilation error :

```
final Iterable<T> anIterable = T[];
```

Comment: "crashing" is a term that you use for severe crash situations at runtime. A compiler giving you an error message is not crashing. Being a good programmer is about being aware of such things :-)

Comment: "Because the following crashes with an incomptaible types compilation error" both of your examples use invalid syntax anyway.

Answer (score 5):

An `Iterable` is an object all unto itself.  An array is an object all unto itself.  These two things are *not* the same object or the same type or the same *anything*.  They have *literally* no relationship - hierarchial or otherwise - between themselves.

Fortunately, the enhanced-`for` statement [is overloaded to accept both arrays and `Iterable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), so you don't need to fuss with this.